# How can expose props types and use it in styled components

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I'm sorry for my poor English, I'll try my best.

Hello i'm new to Styled component.

I want to change style of button and wrap it.

But when I tried to deliver the prop of the wrapping component to the Styled Component, I got a type error.

I don't know what I did wrong.

Below is my code.

```js
// Button/styles.ts
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Button = styled.button<React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>>`
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  &:focus-visible {
    outline: none;
  }
`
```

```js
// Button/Button.ts
import React from 'react'
import * as Styles from './styles'

export type ButtonProps = React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) =>
  <Styles.Button {...props}/> // << TypeError!

export default Button
```

--- edit

I attach my syntax error message.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button">` instead of `React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>`.

`HTMLProps` has a too-wide type.

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase/